# php image upload -works on remote, but not local server

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

Using a very simple script to upload images.
It works fine on my remote server.
However on my local server the uploaded image has a size of 0kb.
I have checked the php.ini file:

```
post_max_size = 40M
upload_max_filesize = 5M
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
```

all these files have read / write permissions set for everyone.

The file test.php contains the form:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This calls file 'test2.php'

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$allow = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "GIF", "PNG");
$todir = 'uploads/';
if (!!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ){ // is the file uploaded yet?
    $info = explode('.', strtolower( $_FILES['file']['name']) );
    if ( in_array( end($info), $allow)){ // is this file allowed
       if ( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $todir . $_FILES['file']['name']);
            // the file has been moved correctly
        }else{
            // error this file ext is not allowed
        }
    }
}
?>
```

No errors are returned Please help am pulling my hair out!!!

Comment: `// is the file uploaded yet?{` is that brace in the correct place?

Comment: `!!$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` double exclamation mark? Why not simply `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`. You should use `is_uploaded_file` for this.

Comment: I made a bit of a typo and have now corrected the code. I am a bit of a newby at php. This script was pulled from another related question. Where would I implement is_uploaded_file?

Comment: Have tried script to: if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])){ etc. Same result with 0kb size.